# Python3 the same url,using urllib.request failed but requests succeed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

l feel puzzled.
My idea is that I want to  send request to the url, and then extract the POST data in the web page, and then sent to the web page.When l used the urllib.request in python,l failed,but instead that l used the requests,it works!
Please tell me why....
Here is the code,and the annotation is code which l used urllib.request

```
import urllib.request
import http.cookiejar
import re
import requests


loginUrl='https://passport.csdn.net/account/login?from=http://my.csdn.net/my/mycsdn'

#Here is the urllib.request code
#cookies=http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar()
#handler=urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies)
#opener=urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
headers={
        'Origin': 'http://passport.csdn.net',
        'Referer':'http://passport.csdn.net/account/login?from=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.csdn.net%2Fmy%2Fmycsdn',
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36 LBBROWSER'
        }

#Here is the requests code
s = requests.Session()
data = s.get(loginUrl)
data = data.text
#request = urllib.request.Request(loginUrl)
#response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
#data = response.read().decode('utf-8')


#l get the value of lt and execution from the web page
pattern_lt = re.compile('<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="(.*?)" />',re.S)
lt = re.findall(pattern_lt,data)
lt = lt[0]
pattern_exe = re.compile('<input type="hidden" name="execution" value="(.*?)" />',re.S)
exe = re.findall(pattern_exe,data)
exe = exe[0]
postDict = {
        'username':'qinyufeng_hdq@163.com',
        'password':'csdn690076598',
        'lt':lt,
        'execution':exe,
        '_eventId':'submit'
        }
r = s.post(loginUrl, data=postDict)
#postData = urllib.parse.urlencode(postDict).encode()
#request = urllib.request.Request(loginUrl, postData,headers)
#response = opener.open(request)
#data = response.read().decode('UTF-8')
print (r.text)
```

l'm not good at English and l hope you get my idea and thank you for reading my problem.

Comment: Did you try working with fiddler to check how exactly the two requests look like? I guess they are not exactly the same (might be different headers, or not following redirect). It should help get the idea what is wrong there and how to fix it.

Comment: thank your for your answer. And l knew that there were some different headers.:)

Comment: Came across this today (6 years later!) And I was amazed